# text editor with graphic comments

Tags: text-editor

I am a programmer and I am looking for a text editor that can display images in comments. The reason is that when I am documenting some functions, I very often find myself wanting to describe them with images instead of words.

Do this kind of text editors exist?

The file doesn't contain image, it contains links to images or other types of files (in comments), the editor just displays them inline, for the pleasure of the user.

Cross-platform is preferred, or at least it should support Unix-like system such as Linux or OS X.

What programming language one uses shouldn't matter at all, as long as the syntax definition is clear.

Take the following haskell code as an example:

```
-- Definition of foldn
foldn c h = g where
  g 0 = c
  g n = h $ g (n - 1)

-- # Fibonacci with foldn
-- ![fib](img/fib.png)
fib = let
  f (m, n) = (n, m + n)
  outl (m, n) = m in
    outl . foldn (0, 1) f
```

This should be rendered in the text editor as:

```
-- Definition of foldn
foldn c h = g where
  g 0 = c
  g n = h $ g (n - 1)
```

## Fibonacci with foldn

[image]

```
fib = let
  f (m, n) = (n, m + n)
  outl (m, n) = m in
    outl . foldn (0, 1) f
```

Comment: We need a few more details to give good answers here. What OS must be supported by that editor? What comments are you talking about: inline the code, or in a separate text file? In the latter case, what formats are preferred? If inline: what programming languages are targeted?

Comment: These info have been added.

Comment: Much as I like the sound of this, it's a **huge** step backwards from an IDE to an editor. Are you truly willing to forgo a debugger just for that? I would advise you to stick with a good IDE and add in-line comments with the path to the image.

Comment: No, you don't have to sacrifice any of IDE or editor functionalities, it's just a richer rendering.

Comment: Thanks, clearer now. But if the programming language doesn't matter, we could recommend you one suited for Visual Basic only, and it would fit your requirements. I doubt you'd be happy with that ;) Do you rather mean it should support as many as possible? As none has full support for all of them, which ones are a must to be covered? What about auto-completion, syntax highlighting, code folding, and all those other features one might wish for or expect in a "programmers editor"?

Comment: Yeah, in a perfect world all these functions should be there,  :). But if you have a candidate closest to these expectations, please post it as an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you looking for an editor, and not a code documentation software? For example, [Doxygen](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/) lets you include links to images in the source code, then shows the images when you compile the code into an `.html`, `.chm`, and/or `.pdf` files. It also supports equations. If I understand the question correctly, the only difference would be the extra compilation step

Answer (score 1):

[CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com) editor (free, open source) can do it. You need to install plugin "Insert Pics" from "Plugins - Addon Manager - Install".

With plugin installed, open any text file, call plugin commands: "Plugins - Insert Pics - .....", it can add picture files into text, can del them later. It saves pictures to separate files [filename].cuda-pic.

[image: Test of picture in file]